# error redirect from /index to /AdminPage nuxt.js middleware

Tags: authentication, navigation, nuxt.js, middleware

[can anyone resolve this error???, this error appear after redirect from /index using middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2KT.png)

this is my middleware code that make users cant go to login(index) page

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    if (process.server) return
    const {verifyJwt} = useUserData()
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const userAuth = await verifyJwt(token)
    if (to.path == '/') {
        if (token) {
            // return navigateTo('/adminPage')
            if (userAuth.message == "Token Expired") {
                localStorage.removeItem('token')
                return navigateTo(to.fullPath)
            }
            else {
                if (userAuth.data.us_role == "KABAG QC") {
                    return navigateTo('/AdminPage',)
                }
                else if (userAuth.data.us_role == "SPV QC") {
                    return navigateTo('/qcPage')
                }
                else if (userAuth.data.us_role == "QC") {
                    return navigateTo('/qcPage')
                }
                else if (userAuth.data.us_role == "KABAG PRODUKSI") {
                    return navigateTo('/produksiPage')
                }
                else if (userAuth.data.us_role == "SPV PRODUKSI") {
                    return navigateTo('/produksiPage')
                }
                else if (userAuth.data.us_role == "PRODUKSI") {
                    return navigateTo('/produksiPage')
                }
                else if(userAuth.data.us_role == "HRD") {
                    return navigateTo('/adminPage')
                }
            }
            // console.log(userAuth)
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!token) {
            return navigateTo('/')
        }
    }


})
```

this is my script code in index(login page)

```
import { deleteUser, login, getUser } from '../function/User/FetchUser'
const { verifyJwt } = useUserData()
const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const loading = ref(false)
const userData = ref(null)
onMounted(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    userData.value = await verifyJwt(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    loading.value = false
})



async function loginData() {
  loading.value = true
  const userData = {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
  }
  const res = await login(userData)
  loading.value = false
  if (res.data == null) {
    alert(res.message)
  }
  else {
    const userData = res.data
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)
    if (userData.us_role == "KABAG QC") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai Kabag QC")
      await navigateTo('/qcPage')
    }
    else if (userData.us_role == "SPV QC") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai SPV QC")
      navigateTo('/qcPage')
    }
    else if (userData.us_role == "QC") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai QC")
      navigateTo('/qcPage')
    }
    else if (userData.us_role == "KABAG PRODUKSI") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai Kabag Produksi")
      navigateTo('/produksiPage')
    }
    else if (userData.us_role == "SPV PRODUKSI") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai SPV Produksi")
      navigateTo('/produksiPage')
    }
    else if (userData.us_role == "PRODUKSI") {
      alert("Anda Login Sebagai Produksi")
      navigateTo('/produksiPage')
    }
  }

}
```

it always showing error after redirected,
i want to clear this error, or maybe this error has no impact to my project??